# How to Have Multiple inheritance in Robot Framework Library file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, robotframework

I would like to have a setup like shown below in my Library file in python for robot framework.

```py
Class Main(foo):
    def common_functions():
       pass

Class Child1(Main):
    def something_unique_child1():
       pass

Class Child2(Main):
    def something_unique_child2():
      pass
```

> However , to use these classes , I would have to import them in
>   the .robot file individually like so :-

```
Library                 python_filename . Child1
Library                 python_filename . Child2
```

Now. The problem is , If I need to use the "Common_functions()" keyword , Robot throws an error stating that there are **"Multiple Keywords with the same name"**

I am guessing that since that function is accessible by both the subclasses , its getting confused.

How does one achieve this functionality in RF?

***Additional Info:***
The reason I would like to have inheritance(as it has been pointed out to me that is not the best way to write libraries) is because there is a feature which has multiple functionalities under it , think of it like a menu feature

> ( **File-->close , File--> save , File --> save as**)

Now , This **"Save"** feature in itself has a lot of sub features" so opening the application and going to "File-->save" is a repetitive step which I have to do again and again for all the sub features.

I was thinking of putting this and a few other repetitive steps in a base class and simply inherit the function onto the sub features as to avoid code repetition.

Comment: What are you wanting your child classes to inherit from the main class? What problem is that solving?

Comment: @BryanOakley  I have edited the question and added additional info.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to import all three classes. Since `Child2` inherits from `Main`, and `Child1` inherits from `Main`, all you have to do is import `Child1` and `Child2` to get all of the keywords from all three classes.

However, if you need all of the keywords, you can have `Child2` inherit from `Child1`, and then you can just import `Child2` to get all of the keywords.

If you insist on wanting to import all three, there are two things you can do.

First, you can fully qualify the keyword so that robot knows which library to use. For example, `Child1.common_functions`.

The other thing you can do is to use the [Set library search order](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Library%20Search%20Order) built-in keyword to tell robot which library to use when there are conflicts.

Comment: `Child2` does not inherit from `Child1`.

Comment: @chepner: my bad. I'll rephrase my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I tried this but the issue is that when a new keyword is added it needs to import the previous class and this new on has to be updated in the .robot file and the old reference needs to be removed. In other words, Imagine that these subclasses perform totally different things, Doing this will cause confusion in the future to someone who might not understand why a totally irrelevant class is being inherited.

Comment: @Anarach: I don't understand your comment at all. The only confusion being added is when you try to use inheritance for libraries. This is not an optimal way to write keyword libraries. You're explicitly causing multiple libraries to have the same keywords. If you remove the inheritance, you remove the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with qualified keyword name? Specifying the library which should provide the keyword, when there's a name conflict (like in your case):

```
python_filename.Main.Common Functions
```

And if typing out the full library.class is too cumbersome, you could import them with an alias - `WITH NAME`, and use it:

```
Library                 python_filename.Child2    WITH NAME    c2
....
c2.Common Functions
```

Comment: Oh.. but , anytime I add a new common function in the main class, I would have to come here and update this .robot file right?

Comment: That's the problem in general with diamond inheritance - it's ambiguous where a common method comes from. And RF has left the decision with the user - fails when you use such method (as you saw), leaving it to you to be explicit which one you actually need.

Comment: @TodorMinakov There is no ambiguity; the MRO defines exactly which class is used for any particular method lookup.

Comment: Which is python's (as the language) chosen resolution for the problem; other languages have other (java - the easiest, no multiple inheritance). Robot Framework does have ambiguity though - it exposes all class methods as keywords, being accessed w/o qualifier. And when you hit a collision, the framework's designers have chosen no to force a position, but to leave this to the user - by failing, as demonstrated in OP's question. @chepner

Comment: @TodorMinakov: robot lets the user decide the order. That's what the [set library search order](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Library%20Search%20Order) keyword is specifically for.

Comment: Yes, it does, I don't argue with that; it's another way for the user to decide it, w/o the framework forcing one solution or another.