# python class inheritence in robotframework

Tags: python, class, inheritance, robotframework, keyword

I have made a python class which will use as library in robotframework

python file name is : myclass.py

Code as follows:

```
class myclass:

        def test0(self):
        
            print("Test 0 start now.....")

class MyTestClass1(myclass):
    
        def test1(self):

            print("Test 1 start now.....")

class MyTestClass2(myclass):

    def test2(self):

            print("Test 2 start now.....")
```

after that, i have made a robot test case file

robot file name is : test.robot

code as follows:

```
*** Settings ***

Library  myclass.py  WITH NAME   my

*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***

TEST

    STEP1

*** Keywords ***

STEP1

    my.test0
```

It's work when i execute the robot test case with above code

But when i change the test case as below:

```
*** Settings ***

Library  myclass.MyTestClass1   WITH NAME   my

*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***

TEST

    STEP1

*** Keywords ***

STEP1

    my.test1
```

It does not work as "ModuleNotFoundError".

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test                                                                                                            | FAIL |
1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
========================================================================================================================
Output:  C:\Users\zhouvjie\oitefw\report\Test-Output-20230710-100003.xml
Log:     C:\Users\zhouvjie\oitefw\report\Test-Log-20230710-100003.html

[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\zhouvjie\oran_ta_framework\TestData\CU_Plane\test.robot' on line 2: Importing library 'myclass.MyTestClass1' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myclass'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  None
PYTHONPATH:
  C:\Users\zhouvjie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\robot.exe
  C:\Users\zhouvjie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python310.zip
  C:\Users\zhouvjie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs
  C:\Users\zhouvjie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
  C:\Users\zhouvjie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310
  C:\Users\zhouvjie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages
  C:\Users\zhouvjie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\robotide\contrib\testrunner\../../lib
Report:  C:\Users\zhouvjie\oitefw\report\Test-Report-20230710-100003.html

Test finished 20230710 10:00:03
```

It's seem the method of "python_filename.classname" can not work this way in robotframework?

Here's another answer of multiple inheritance use in robotframework

[How to Have Multiple inheritance in Robot Framework Library file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56947023/how-to-have-multiple-inheritance-in-robot-framework-library-file)

suppose it's same way with my solution, can anyone help me how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should name your class the same as your file and make a different file for each class. You can then import them seperately and it should work as expected.

Alternatively if you don't specifically need classes, you can just make a file without a class and only functions. You can then import the file and use all functions as keywords.